# Can I share a ViewModel between an activity and a service?

Tags: android, android-activity, mvvm, service, viewmodel

I have an app that runs a service, which should continue working even when the app is closed. I need to share info between them, and I want to try doing this using a ViewModel. I know how to share a ViewModel between fragmments, but between an activity and service escapes me. Does anyone know?

Comment: What's the role of a _view_model in conjunction with a service?

Comment: I have a class that tracks sensor data that needs to be accessed by MainActivity and also by the service. I can create two objects, but since it's the same data, it'd be redundant and I'd have to worry about starting/stopping each properly. A shared ViewModel would be preferred

Comment: Sure, you only store the data once. But I just can't imagine what a service might want to do with a view model. I'd rather put the data in a (classic, non-android) service and acces that from your (android) service and your view model.

Answer (score 0):

@Elliptica

My solution:

1) Your activities and services must run on same process !

2) Make a `BaseSupportViewModelService` class that has `ViewModelStore` to store your `ShareViewModel`.

3) Your `ViewModel` must be shareable! How to share `ViewModel` between two activities (maybe three) or service.

Here's a [link1](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29#issuecomment-407291032)

Here's a [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51605781/9656066)

Hope it helps you.