# Android Components ViewModel across activitis

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-components

In **Android Components** could I make application class as the owner of ViewModel so I use it across several activities?
 or there no walk around?

```
ViewModelProviders.of(application class not activity).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Please see this topic it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641121/share-viewmodel-between-fragments-that-are-in-different-activity

Comment: @IgorOK is there a good article about ViewModelProvider.Factory?

Comment: amorenew not sure. I am looking for the same solution too and I haven't found solution better than discribed on link above. Unfortunately android documentation does not contain information how to share fragment states in different activities like, for example, Gmail application does on tablet (

Answer (score 1):

An `Application` is not a `LifecycleOwner`, so you cannot use it as a scope for a `ViewModel`.

Comment: what about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641121/share-viewmodel-between-fragments-that-are-in-different-activity

Comment: and is  there a good article about  ViewModelProvider.Factory

Comment: @amorenew: Similarly, you could hack a custom subclass of `Application` to be a `LifecycleOwner`. But you are not gaining anything over just having a singleton. Instead, you are making your app more complex for no obvious benefit.