# Update ViewModel between a fragment and an activity

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I just started using the **architecture component** of Android in my app, and I have a use case when:

- A fragment is an observer of `ViewModel`'s `LiveData` (which comes from a `Room` request)
- This fragment starts an activity at some point
- The activity needs to use the same data (as `LiveData` in the fragment) and update it
- The user then returns to the fragment

I tried using the same `ViewModel` class and adding the fragment and activity as observers, thinking that somehow updating from the activity will affect the fragment when returning to it, but it doesn't work.
The two `ViewModel`s seem independent.

How can I **force refresh** the fragment data when returning from the activity (in `onActivityResult` for example)?
Or is it possible to share the same `ViewModel` between the fragment and activity? (though I doubt it since the `ViewModel` is linked to the lifecycle of the observer)

**Fragment**

```
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    ...
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            mAdapter.setData(data);
        }
    });
}

// in an onClick method
startActivity(intent); // go to the Activity
```

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            mPagerAdapter.setData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private Dao dao;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public MyViewModel (@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        dao = AppDatabase.getInstance(application).getDao();
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public LiveData<Data> getData() {
        return dao.getAllData();
    }

    // other methods to update and delete with executorService
}
```

Comment: Life cycles are individual for each activity or freshmen’s, so your two ViewModels would be completely different lifecycles, id recommend maybe send the data over in an Intent when starting the fragment and pushing it back after you’re done (if you aren’t saving it from inside the fragment, otherwise you could just make another call to the room database)

Comment: What you described should work if both activity and fragment use same instance of ViewModel. For this, I use Koin for Dependency Injection.

Comment: Post the ViewModel class too please

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641121/share-viewmodel-between-fragments-that-are-in-different-activity

Comment: Post you viewModel class

Comment: @Brandon I can't send the data since it's a `Room `request result in form of `LiveData`
I tried doing another call when returning from the activity, but it does nothing...
Also, I tried using the `MutableLiveData` but it doesn't work with `Room`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the result you want by seting a common lifecycle owner for the viewmodel, and using the same viewModel at the different fragments.
Inside my fragment, i get the view model like this:

INSIDE FRAGMENT:

```
 var userViewModel = activity?.run{ViewModelProviders.of(this, SharedUserViewModel.MainActivityViewModelFactory(applicationContext))[SharedUserViewModel::class.java]}
```

Did you see i use the activity as the "ViewModelProviders.of" parameter?
This way, the view model have the same owner, its working alright for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share ViewMode between activity and Fragment Using SharedViewModel.

Comment: Check this link Please    https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments

Comment: Check https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#5